# Tkinter. Текст накладывается друг на друга. Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Создал программу вывода случайного пароля. Если несколько раз нажать на кнопку вывода, текст будет накладываться друг на друга.

[image: Вот в чем проблема]

Как сделать так чтобы этого наложения не было и текст, который был до этого исчезал?

---

Вот весь код:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from random import choice

app = tk.Tk()
app.title("Генератор пароля")
app.state('zoomed')

sy = ["gz", "fti", "e", ".", "z", "f", "g", "pssa", "wrei", "w", "y", "x", "b", "a"]

def gopass():
    app_name = ttk.Label(app, text="".join(choice(sy) for i in range(5)), font='Times 11', foreground='#171717')
    app_name.grid(row=4, column=1)

btn_search = ttk.Button(app, text="Отправить", width=10, command=gopass)
btn_search.grid(row=1, column=2)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: О боже, зачем такой большой скрин, да и всего экрана? :) Сделайте небольшое окно, пусть окно будет в фокусе и нажмите Alt + PrintScreen после откройте редактор вопроса (кнопка `править`) тыкните в редактор и нажмите Ctrl + V, тогда вставится в вопрос скриншот окна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from random import choice

app = tk.Tk()
app.title("Генератор пароля")

sy = ["gz", "fti", "e", ".", "z", "f", "g", "pssa", "wrei", "w", "y", "x", "b", "a"]

btn_search = ttk.Button(app, text="Отправить", width=10)
btn_search.pack()

app_name = ttk.Label(app, text="default", font='Times 11', foreground='#171717')
app_name.pack()

def gopass():
    app_name["text"] = "" # очищаем Label
    app_name["text"] = "".join(choice(sy) for i in range(5))

btn_search.config(command=gopass)

app.mainloop()
```